# I'm having trouble with my lottery generator

Tags: bash

What I'm experiencing is there are no lottery tickets generated. After running the script, the user is prompted for a MaxValue, a NumValues (numbers per line), and the number of lottery numbers they'd like. This was working until I added the checks to ensure non-numeric values, and numbers in NumValues greater than MaxValue resulted in an error message.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter a max random number."
read MaxValue

 if [[ $MaxValue != +([0-9]) ]]
  then
   echo "I can't accept any non-numeric characters. Please try again."
   exit
 fi

echo "Please enter the number of tickets.   "
read NumValues

  if [ $NumValues -gt $MaxValue ]
  then
   echo "The number of values can't be greater than the max random number. Please try again."
    exit
  fi

echo "Please enter how many tickets you'd like. "
read NumSeq

  while [ $NumSeq -gt 0 ]
     do
      touch lotto
      x=$NumValues
      while [ $x -gt 0 ]
      do

      num1=$(($RANDOM * MaxValue))
      num2=$((num1 / 32767))
       if [ `grep -c $num2 lotto` -eq 0 ]
        then
        echo $num2 >> lotto
        x=$((x - 1))
       fi
       done

     NumSeq=$((NumSeq - 1 ))

     echo `sort -n lotto`

     rm lotto
     done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please clarify what the problem or question is? Because this isn't really clear to me. "Having trouble" is not very descriptive. What do you expect to see? What do you actually see? Do you get any errors? Please take a moment to read through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You can always [edit] your question.

Comment: Thank you! The issue I'm having is that nothing is generated, in terms of 'lotto' tickets. What I expect to see after this is successfully executed is a series of random numbers, depending on the MaxValue, NumValues, and NumSeq. The code was working up until I was instructed to add checks to ensure non-numeric values and NumValues(numbers per line) greater than MaxValue resulted in an error.

Comment: Running the script as-is on my system works for me.  Perhaps your problem is related to the specific input parameters that you're using?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but it's working now. Weird. Anyhow, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: If you're already using `[[`, keep using it completely in your script. Avoid `[`.